# 20.04 Unable to shutdown

Tags: nvidia, xorg, suspend, power-management, shutdown

I am currently having issues when trying to shutdown my PC, where it never shuts down after going to a shell terminal.

I currently get: `waiting for proccess: XOrg`, and after two minutes: `XOrg blocked for more than 120 seconds`

It gets stuck at a shell and doesn't shutdown, requiring me to hold the power button for 10 secs to turn it off. Would this do damage to my pc?

I've taken a look at other threads and have tried:

- Changing my NVIDIA drivers to proprietary ones (nvidia-driver-440)
- Adding `acpi=force` to my grub options (removed splash screen option)
- Turning "Blank Screen" to "never" and "automatic suspend" to "off" in settings

Currently, no of these have solved the issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Better to hold ALT + SysRq and type `reisub`, this way it closes down the processes and the machine will reboot.

Comment: I'm using nvidia-driver-390 and it works well. Nvidia X Server settings has also just been updated, so it might solve the problem.

Comment: @Raffles Which graphics card are you using?

Comment: Hi Dan, GeForce GTX 970. Can you say what yours is? It might help others to add the results of `sudo lshw` to your question.

Comment: @Raffles rtx 2070 - is that compatible with that driver you are using?

Comment: The drivers should be compatible with both our cards. It seems that 450.57 is the latest release on the nvidia website so there might have been a bug fixed that affects yours >>> https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/162107/en-us

Comment: BTW don't try install the driver using the .run installer unless you are very familiar how to do it. Rather wait until you can do it with the Additional Drivers feature. Take a look at the README file in the link http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/450.57/README/installdriver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, for anyone running into the same problem as me:

I updated my bios to the latest version and now everything seems to be running smoothly (I can shut down properly now, without having to force shut down). This is with a Z390 GAMING X motherboard.

Comment: So many things I've tried, yet it was the obvious one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at the logging in `/home/username/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` and `/var/log/syslog`.